# Space maintenance after Space Shuttle Program Shutdown

Tags: artificial-satellite, space-shuttle, maintenance, in-space-repairs

I was wondering, what if one of the satellites that were previously serviced by the space shuttle, like the Hubble Space Telescope, needs repairs now that the shuttle program is off?

Are there other ways to fix them, or if not, what is then going to happen with them?

Comment: @TildalWave Yeah I meant the Hubble Space Telescope and thinks like that, I meant every satellite that had a maintenance by the Shuttle before, what if it needs to be repaired (again), what's going to happen? as the shuttle was the only way to do repairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been proposals for automated servicing systems, and NASA is doing exercises with teleoperated repair systems on the ISS. But as of today, if the Hubble shut down due to a power supply failure, there is nothing that could fix it.

Comment: ...and considering James Webb Telescope is "right behind the corner", I don't think Hubble would be fixed even if we had the means. It's running on extended time, and when it dies, it dies.

Comment: @SF but the JWT isn't meant to replace the HT. The frequencies don't overlap. We would lose a lot of potential science points without the Hubble.